# Layered Left Navigation

Tags: catalog, filter, navigation

I have 4 different themes for 4 different website on the same Magento system. One of the themes has a particular folder on code/local/Magentothem/LayeredNavigationajax whic contents for example the filter.phtml file for the layered navigation of that theme.

The problem is that the rest of the themes are taking this file - filter.phtml on code/local/Magentothem/LayeredNavigation - by default to display the filters, instead of taking the filter.phtml file on their themes.

Any suggestions on how can I fix that? I don't really know how to debug this and check how on theme can take this file from another theme.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There's something terribly wrong with your question.

Comment: What @Tim? Please, just let me know if you need more info or maybe I didn't explain it well... sorry

Answer (score 2):

I've just found the solution. Even when the theme was installed only on one of the websites, the default configuration were being taken by the rest of the themes.

This theme has an option menu on the admin panel, so I needed to go to this option, select the Layer Navigation Filter Ajax and disable it for each store which isn't using this theme.